# Proguard tutorial / configuration file for android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, proguard, android-build, android-proguard

i've been searching for Proguard tutorial or explanatory configuration file all over, i can't find good one, there are very less pages regarding this & no simple explanation/tutorial for beginners.

Please guide me to a tutorial which shows how to use proguard in Android Studio.

**Also tell me how are you using? & your configuration file.**

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

For complete usage explanation of proguard:[this link](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/)

There is no significant difference between Android and Java. You can use all the document/examples in the link. For simplicity, only two things you need to do:

1. build.gradle

   ```
   buildTypes {
   release {
       proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt')
   }
   }...
   ```
2. proguard-android-optimize.txt placed in the directory

   ```
   #duplicate the contents of this file and remove the include of this
    -keep public class * extends android.app.Service
   ...
   ```

Comment: Sorry not helpful, i want explanation with configuration file, or link to tutorial. the links also not helpful